# STS dropins problem

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

ref to http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Installer

I don't know it's there any step I miss?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the spket plugin, but I do know that the greclipse plugin only ships zips of the update site.  You must remove greclipse from the dropins directory, download the zip file and point the p2 installer to the zip file.

Comment: btw,anyway to backup plugin for sts? I had installed sts 2.8.0M1 but hard to move plugins from sts2.7.0 to 2.8. my network is so slow.

Comment: Dropins are used for legacy plugins.  Most plugins should be released through a p2 update site and must be installed through the installer, but some plugins are not part of an update site.  They can be installed through the Dropins folder.  It's not recommended to use.